# HeaderView and FooterView, Xib, StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

Actually i want know that, what is the best way to create header view and footer view in xib.I read some article and got 2 options.
1) I can directly drop the uiview in xib.
2) I can create custom cell and return that cell it self.

But i want to know that, which is the best approach for that.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing one over other won't make much difference, but otherwise

UIView from xib will be better than UItableViewCell as UITableViewCell would have many extra layers inherited above UIView, which is not required by headerView and footerView.

So, go with UIView xib's.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question depends entirely on requirement you have. Both are good but depending on what you want to do with them. To explain this let take some examples

- For cases where you have a long list of items to display and user can select them, `UITableView` is best as we all Know. So in this case if there is some footer which should also scroll down and remain as last item on screen go for `UITableView` as footer.
- Let take login Screen which has username, password, some company brand text and image, etc. and our requirement is to support for device from iPhone 4 to iPhone 6s Plus with footer which contains **login** `UIButton` always visible. In this case you should opt for UIView as footer and put above content in `UIScrollView` or `UITableView` depending which is best.